# Get 5th to last to 3rd to last elements from a list of unknown size

Tags: python, list

I have a list of unknown length which I want to get the 5th to last, 4th to last, and 3rd to last elements from:

So if my list is like. `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I want to get. `b = [6, 7, 8]`

I can get this with `b = a[6:9]`

But the issue is my list could contain any number of items, so it could be.

`a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`

and in this case `b` should be `[9, 10, 11]` which `b = a[6:9]` does not give.

How can I always get the 5th to last third last items in a list, my list will always be over 5 elements long.

Comment: Search and/then use negative indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **negative indexing** with list slices, so `b = a[-5:-2]` will always return your desired list regardless of your original lists size.

**Example 1:**

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> b = a[-5:-2]
>>> b
[6, 7, 8]
```

**Example 2:**

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> b = a[-5:-2]
>>> b
[9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative indexing. `a[-1]` indicates your last element,`a[-2]` indicates your second last element and so on. 
Suppose you want to get last 5 elements. The you can write :

```
my_list = a[-5:]
```

Also follow shash678's answer. 
You can read [What is negative index in Python?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-negative-index-in-Python)

Comment: Is there a specific reason to repeat the previous answer?

Comment: I have added some different explanation and a resource link.

Comment: Well, I consider this worth a comment, especially given that this the n-th duplicate question about basic list slicing. There is a flag duplicates option for a reason.

Comment: Thanks, I shall consider your suggestion in the future.